# Possible To Enter An Entire List in a Text Field with iMacros?

Tags: imacros

**Is it possible to enter a whole row of data into a text box (1 keyword per line) with iMacros?**

**Problem:**

I have a whole list of keywords (Column A in CSV file) I am trying to paste into a text box with iMacros.

All the solutions I've found involve using !LOOP to reload the whole page and extract the keyword row by row, though with ~800 keywords I'm trying to find a more efficient way.

I know I can integrate iMacros with VBA or javascript, but that would also involve looping data entry row by row [albeit a smaller segment of code], though this still seems inefficient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s suppose that the ‘**keywords.txt**’ file is like this:

```
keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
keyword4
keyword5
```

and placed in the default ‘iMacros’ datasource folder. So you can try to read it at once with the help of the following code:

```
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=file:///{{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}/keywords.txt
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAB CLOSE
'PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Note, if you have a more complicated CSV (not TXT) structure of the file, it’s possible to use the JavaScript Scripting Interface (for Firefox extension) in order to read and process it efficiently as well.

Comment: Thank you Shugar for the help- I was trying to load an entire list in a text box, not extract it, but I will keep this answer for reference since it was also helpful. 
I realized I just have to save the list as a .csv file from notepad and insert quotation marks before the first keyword and after the last. 
One thing I'm trying to figure out now is how to have the script loop through so it loads multiple csv files and do the exact same process (ie. 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv...100.csv, etc)... any suggestions?